# How to run multiple queries simultaneously and save the results to different variables when you aren't sure how many queries you will be running

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 arrays of queries, but I'm not sure how many queries I have in each array until runtime. I would like to save the results from each array of queries to a variable (e.g. queries from the 1st array should be saved to the 1st array and queries from the 2nd array should be saved to the 2nd). I was going to use promise.all() but I don't know how to assign only some of the responses to 1 array and some to the other. Something like the following:

```
async function runQueriesAndGetResponse() {
    var queryArray1 = [query, anotherQuery, 3rdQuery,...]
    var queryArray2 = [4thQuery, 5thQuery, 6thQuery,...]
    return await Promise.all(queryArray1.concat(queryArray2))
}

var [responses1, responses2] = await runQueriesAndGetResponse()
// Doesn't work because responses1 and responses2 will only have the 1st and 2nd response respectively
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an array from your function, where each element is the `Promise.all` of each of your `queryArray`

Basically the return value of your function should be
`return [await Promise.all(queryArray1), await Promise.all(queryArray2)];`